# Facebook Meta tag error - Meta tags in body and Og:Image is not working Giving me wrong images

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags, meta

I have an issue with Facebook meta tags (Open Graph Protocol). Facebook Object debugger says that I have the meta tags in body but I don't think so since everything was working fine until yesterday. But now it is throwing me an error. Also `og:image` tag is not returning the correct image that has to be parsed via the Object Debugger. I see some warnings like

```
Errors That Must Be Fixed
Meta Tags In Body   Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree.
Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable.
Notice

Like Button Warnings That Should Be Fixed
Admins And App ID Missing   fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing. These tags are necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.
Like Button Tag Missing og:title is missing. The og:title meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.
Like Button Tag Missing og:type is missing. The og:type meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.
Like Button Tag Missing og:image is missing. The og:image meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.
Notice

Warnings That Should Be Fixed
Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

I have everything in the right place; I am not able to detect the issue.

Here is the URL of the website
http://circoviral.com/fotos-curiosas-escalofrios/

Almost every post have this problem.

Comment: There is a link to what Facebook sees on the debugger page. This is what facebook sees https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fcircoviral.com%2Ffotos-curiosas-escalofrios%2F . The og-tags are inside <body>

Comment: If you debug this post you will find that all the og tags are inside the head tag.

Comment: If you follow the link I posted you see that they are not when Facebook request the page

Comment: But when i debug the code in inspect element.  It appears before the body tag

Comment: Debug your server and see why it returns something different when Facebook request the page

Comment: What do you mean by debug your server

Comment: Go to the link I posted. When you load that a request will be sent to your server. Debug your code and see why it returns what it does

Comment: Thanks for your help wizKid,  but i don't know how to debug my code when request sent to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, there is a problem with no script tag. If you include it in your head.  When Facebook debug the url and found NoScript tag in the head then it will put all the meta tags and script inside body of the document And we will get a error that the meta tags are in body.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: try to remove the noscript tag or find it's source from where it is coming.